# GIMP animation question

Tags: gimp

Is it possible to create an animation in GIMP that will loop only certain number of times and then stop playing?

I see there is an option that allows looping forever.

But I want the animation to stop after looping 5 times or say 30 seconds not play forever.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the GIMP interface, the simple answer is "no."

That said, presuming you are creating an Animated GIF, look at the the **Animated GIF** section on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format

Note that the 2-byte entry at offset 31D (797 decimal) is `FF FF`, from experience, this `-1` for non-stop repeats.

You could manually change these two bytes (with `\005\000` for 5 times).  I just tried this and it worked for me.

Good luck.

Comment: That is cool if possible. But how do I edit that entry at 31D offset??

Comment: http://www.google.com/#q=binary+editors - I did it from the command line on Linux, but that's not for the faint of heart!

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to output a set of image files (like a1.png, a2.png, a3.png ...) from GIMP and then use imagemagick to create the gif.  You would use:

```
convert *.png -loop 1 out.gif
```

You can set how many times you want it to loop.  If you use 0, it will loop forever.

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/#loop

Answer (score 0):

You could manually repeat the sequence of images as many times over as necessary, but that would result in an incredibly large file, so that might not be the way you want to go.

Comment: Photoshop has an option on how many times I want to loop. Unfortunately GIMP doesn't have it. Trying to see if any other free tools has this option